# Each em data JSON jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando percorrer um `array de objetos` com jquery estou fazendo assim:

```
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/produtos', function(data) {
        $(data).each(function (item) {
            console.log(item);
            $('.product-slider').append(item.NmProduto);
        });

        console.log(data);
    });
```

No primeiro `console.log(item)` está saindo `0 1 2 3`.
Ja no comando `$('.product-slider').append(item.NmProduto);` não está fazendo nada e se eu do console log no `item.NmProduto` sai `undefined`, ja em meu `console.log(data)` está vindo as informações certinho como a no print a seguir:

[image: console.log da data vindo do jquery]

Preciso setar um html nesta `div` minha com os dados vindo do `json`, qual é a melhor forma de desenvolver isto ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está pegando a `chave` do `array` e precisa na verdade do **valor**, então use [***$.each***](https://api.jquery.com/each/) dessa forma:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/produtos', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
        //console.log(item);
        $('.product-slider').append(item.NmProduto);
    });
});
```

[Exemplos de como utilizar array com jQuery](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-each-function-examples/).